# Passing element value to Ajax using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to pass the **value** from an anchor tag into ajax.

**This is my HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="nav-section">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="section" value="news">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="section" value="highlights">Highlights</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

I use this script to retrieve, and send to ajax. This is where I run into trouble. I can alert the value, using `alert(value)`, but when I pass it like so: `post_id: value`, no data is send.

**Script**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.section').click(function () {
        var value = $('.section').attr('value');
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action':'ajax_action',
                    'type':'post',
                    'post_id': value
                },
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
        });     
    });  
});
```

When I `var_dump` the id, I get a null value. The function is running but has no data.
When all of this is done i want to use the value to retrieve a `get_template_part` in wordpress, and pass it in to the html.

**AJAX in functions.php**

```
function ajax_action_stuff() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id']; 
    var_dump($post_id);
    echo $post_id;
    die(); // 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` to target the element which was clicked. This way, you only get the value of the attribute `value`, whose element was clicked upon.

```
var value = $(this).attr('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
  var value = $(this).attr('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('.section').click(function () {
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'action':'ajax_action','type':'post','post_id': value },
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });     
        });  
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me. As most of you mentioned, using $this instead .class, is ofcourse the right choice. Ty for teaching me how to pass to data from a html tag to AJAX using Jquery. The important thing for anyone passing by is the "   data: {'action':'ajax_action','type':'post','post_id': value },". I effing love this forum!